# Angular: passing index of object array from ng-repeat to access object data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of objects displayed with ng-repeat:

```
<div class = "row" ng-repeat="article in academicArticles">
    <div class = "col-md-9 academicArticle" ng-click = "index = $index">
        <a ui-sref ="article">
            <h2> {{article.title}} </h2>
            <p> {{academicArticles.indexOf(article)}} </p>
            <img src = "{{article.img}}" class = "img-responsive">
     </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the selected "article" in another state. Right now I have:

```
<div class ="container">
  <div class = "jumbotron">
    <img src = "../../../photos/danielpark.jpg">
    <h1>{{academicArticles[index].title}}</h1>
    <p> Written By: {{academicArticles[index].author}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

No errors but `{{academicArticles[index].author}}` and `{{academicArticles[index].title}` are blank. How can I access the data of the selected article in another sate?

Comment: Simplest would be use url param to pass the article id in url and in other state get that article using the id. For link would be like `ui-sref ="article({id:article.id})"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that by passing the index of the selected "article" as state parameter to the other state.
assume the other state called state2, you need to add the state parameter to the state in the router registration, for example, if you rigstered the new state like this, you can add the index as follow

```
$stateProvider.state("state2", {
                url: '/state2/:index',
                templateUrl:'state2.html',
                controller: 'state2Controller'});
```

and then in state2Controller you can access the index parameter using stateParams service like this :

```
 (function() {

           angular
              .module("app")
              .controller("state2Controller", state2Controller);

           state2Controller.$inject = ["$scope", "$stateParams"];
           function state2Controller($scope, $stateParams){
            $scope.index = $stateParams.index;

           }
        })()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to pass the entire object as a state param? something like   url: '/state2/:article',

Comment: you cant pass the hole object directly, but you can add parameters as much as you want, you need to update the state to be like this $stateProvider.state("state2", {
                url: '/state2/:index?param1&param2&param3'            and then in  ui-serf you can use it like this ui-sref ="article({index:article.index, param1: article.params1})"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trapped by `ng-repeat` scope issue, the trick is not bind primitive types to scope directly instead use some object like `$scope.model` and `$scope.model.authorId`